# Grub rescue not found 'grub_divmod64' and 'grub_realidt'

Tags: grub

A 'ls (hd1,msdos1)/boot/grub/i386-pc/' in grub rescue shows all modules and i find there 'linux.mod' and 'normal.mod'. 
But when i make

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd1,msdos1)/boot/grub/i386-pc
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: symbol not found: 'grub_divmod64'.
grub rescue> insmod linux
error: symbol not found: 'grub_realidt'
```

What's the problem?

I search too much and found very few... just stuff.
I have installed a Trisquel 7.0 LTS Belenos on AMD64.

Answer (score 0):

Trisquel is derived from another distribution, namely Ubuntu. Boot
from a live Ubuntu CD and select "repair mode", then continue as if
installing. Eventually there will be a repair menu and one of the
options will be to re-install grub. Don't forget to enter the root
of the drive before continuing, i.e. something like /dev/sda (without
a partition number).

Comment: Thanks... after this problem, i chossen to migrate to Debian!